# Gloss Parsing unexpectedly found nil

Tags: json, swift, parsing, null

I have an object like this that is a `Dictionary<String,AnyObject>`:

```
["velocity": 0.0, "constant_b": 0.0, "created_at": 2016-10-10T01:02:04Z, "shot_date": 2016-10-08T00:29:52.596+00:00, "time": 2016-10-10T01:02:04Z, "shot_origin_y": 0.0, "peak_ball_height": 0.0, "shot_origin_x": 0.0, "made": null, "date": 2016-10-10T01:02:04Z, "constant_a": 0.0, "shot_length": 0.0, "ball_position_y": 0.0, "lr": 0.0, "depth": 0.0, "id": 2517999, "clean_make": null, "location_id": 1, "player_id": null, "ball_position_x": 0.0, "entry_angle": 0.0, "constant_c": 0.0]
```

When passed into my object like this (This uses GLOSS, a cocoapod for parsing JSON objects):

```
Shot(json: shotJSON)
```

I get unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value, but id is clearly there and is clearly and integer.

Here is the gloss object:

```
import Foundation
import Gloss

class Shot: Decodable, FAURequestsDecodable, Equatable{

    let id:Int
    let velocity:Double?
    let time:NSDate?
    let shotOriginY:Double?
    let shotOriginX:Double?
    let shotLength:Double?
    let shotDate:NSDate?
    let playerId:Int?
    let peakBallHeight:Double?
    let made:Bool?
    let lr:Double?
    let locationId:Int?
    let entryAngle:Double?
    let depth:Double?
    let date:NSDate?
    let createdAt:NSDate?
    let constantC:Double?
    let constantB:Double?
    let constantA:Double?
    let cleanMake:Bool?
    let ballPositionY:Double?
    let ballPositionX:Double?

    let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()

    //Mark: - Deserialization
    required init?(json: JSON){
        self.id = ("id" <~~ json)!
        self.velocity = "velocity" <~~ json
        self.shotOriginY = "shot_origin_y" <~~ json
        self.shotOriginX = "shot_origin_x" <~~ json
        self.shotLength = "shot_length" <~~ json
        self.playerId = "player_id" <~~ json
        self.peakBallHeight = "peak_ball_height" <~~ json
        self.made = "made" <~~ json
        self.lr = "lr" <~~ json
        self.locationId = "location_id" <~~ json
        self.entryAngle = "entry_angle" <~~ json
        self.depth = "depth" <~~ json
        self.constantC = "constant_c" <~~ json
        self.constantB = "constant_b" <~~ json
        self.constantA = "constant_a" <~~ json
        self.cleanMake = "clean_make" <~~ json
        self.ballPositionY = "ball_position_y" <~~ json
        self.ballPositionX = "ball_position_x" <~~ json

        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-dd-MM'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'"
        self.createdAt = Decoder.decodeDate("created_at", dateFormatter: dateFormatter)(json)
        self.date = Decoder.decodeDate("date", dateFormatter: dateFormatter)(json)
        self.time = Decoder.decodeDate("time", dateFormatter: dateFormatter)(json)

        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-dd-MM'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS"
        self.shotDate = Decoder.decodeDate("shot_date", dateFormatter: dateFormatter)(json)
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that is the line where it crashes? Could there be a problem with the implementation of your custom `<~~` operator? Could there be a problem with the construction of your `JSON` object?

Comment: It's using GLOSS, a cocoapod. The operator is defined in that and works fine for all my other Decodable objects. It's just this one parse that dies. And yeah it's the self.id = lines. There are no other non-optionals in the init and the debugger also notes that line, @MatthewSeaman.